# Replace CSS :hover to :active with JS on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove hover effects on touch devices. I know it's better to use hover class for hover effect instead of hover pseudo class since it's easier to remove later on, but since I already coded my site, I can't change all of it now, but I found a good solution that targets all :hover pseudo classes in CSS and replaces them to :active. :active pseudo class works fine for what I want to accomplish, however I have some difficulties with JS code. There are probably some mistakes but I am not able to find them.

```js
function touch() {
  if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    var sheet = document.getElementById("#pagestyle");
    if (sheet.cssRules) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
        var rule = sheet.cssRules[i];
        if (rule.selectorText) {
          rule.selectorText = rule.selectorText.replace(':hover', ':active');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.test:hover {}
```

```html
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing bunch of code in JS, why don't you simply add a rule in stylesheet?

```
.test:hover,
.test:active {
}
```

---

I couldn't understand why you are not adding `:active` rule as above but if you really only want to put css for those `:hover` and no-hover devices, then you can use media query like:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
  .test:hover { }
}
@media (hover: none) {
  .test:active { }
}
```

There's also:

```
/* the device does not include any pointing device. */
@media (any-pointer: none) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You can read more about these on [medium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983889/replace-css-hover-to-active-with-js-on-touch-devices)

Hope, you find it useful. But in my opinion, this step is really unnecessary. As demonstrated in first code example will be much better than having anything like that.

Comment: That way I am just adding :active pseudo class for the element but not removing :hover!

Comment: why you want to remove hover effect?

Comment: Because hover effect doesn't work good on touch devices, obviously! It looks bad.

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile devices but having it in the  stylesheet has no bad effect.

Comment: Then, let me know what happens on mobile devices when it has hover rule?

Comment: Updated my answer if that helps you.

Comment: For example, when I click on a button that has hover effect, it remains in the hover state until you click somewhere else.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my problem. On touch device, it still acts the same. The only way is JS code I posted which needs to be edited.

Comment: Again, the easiest way is to make minor changes in JS code I provided, it will do everything automatically with a few lines of the code.

Comment: I don't think js will replace stylesheet rule as what you're talking.